How to show arrow in split header of CListCtrl permanently
I have a CListCtrl and modify the header of it like split header with arrow which allow to choose from menu items:
CHeaderCtrl* pHeaderCtrl = m_cTree.GetHeaderCtrl();
if (pHeaderCtrl)
{
    //BOOL bb = pHeaderCtrl->ModifyStyle(0, pHeaderCtrl->GetStyle() | HDS_BUTTONS);
    // Modify the header item style to include the split button style
    HDITEM item;
    item.mask = HDI_FORMAT;
    //item.iItem = 0; // Index of the header item you want to modify
    pHeaderCtrl->GetItem(0, &item);
    item.fmt |= HDF_SPLITBUTTON;
    pHeaderCtrl->SetItem(0, &item);
}

The arrow in header shows only if the mouse goes over the header. The user does not know that he can choose some choice. How to show this arrow permanently?
Standard look:

When mouse goes over:


You can draw an arrow to prompt the user.

I dont understand...

@MichalHadraba I think MinxinYu is suggesting you enable the HDF_OWNERDRAW flag on the header item, and then subclass the list/header to handle the WM_DRAWITEM message. See Owner-Drawn Header Controls

@MichalHadraba another option would be to create an image list holding some arrow images, and then assign that image list to the header, and then enable the item's HDF_IMAGE flag and specify an image index in the item's iImage field.

Have you tried to use a CMFCListCtrl instead?

No, because I use my own MyCListCtrl based partly on CListCtrl and partly on CTreeCtrl.

Have you tried customed draw?

Searched it a little but it seems there isn't some straightforward solution, eg like a flag you can set and make it work. As suggested by others, the best you can do is implement an owner-drawn header control for your list control class. It may be tricky to write that painting code, taking into account so many styles, states and user actions and their combinations, but you can take code fragments from CMFCHeaderCtrl::OnPaint() and CMFCHeaderCtrl::OnDrawItem() in the MFC sources. This split-button feature isn't much used as it seems, since searching the web returns very few results.

Without more context on the implementation of your CListCtrl it's difficult to give a satisfying fully-ready solution, but I tried to overwrite the way you did to test it.
I overwrote CHeaderList to redraw the arrow and force it to appears all the time.
class CCustomHeaderCtrl : public CHeaderCtrl
{
protected:
    afx_msg void OnPaint()
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);

        HDITEM item = { HDI_FORMAT | HDI_TEXT };
        TCHAR szText[256];
        item.pszText = szText;
        item.cchTextMax = 255;

        for (int i = 0; i < GetItemCount(); ++i)
        {
            GetItem(i, &item);
            CRect itemRect;
            GetItemRect(i, &itemRect);

            dc.DrawText(item.pszText, &itemRect, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_SINGLELINE);

            if (item.fmt & HDF_SPLITBUTTON)
            {
                itemRect.left = itemRect.right - 16;
                DrawFrameControl(dc, &itemRect, DFC_SCROLL, DFCS_SCROLLDOWN);
            }
        }
    }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCustomHeaderCtrl, CHeaderCtrl)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()

If this is too long, keep track of the DrawFrameControl(dc, &arrowRect, DFC_SCROLL, DFCS_SCROLLDOWN) that can help you to rewrote the arrow.
From your snippet, I added my class


if (CHeaderCtrl* pHeaderCtrl = m_cTree.GetHeaderCtrl())
{
    HDITEM item = { HDI_FORMAT };
    int columnCount = pHeaderCtrl->GetItemCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; ++i)
    {
        pHeaderCtrl->GetItem(i, &item);
        item.fmt |= HDF_SPLITBUTTON;
        pHeaderCtrl->SetItem(i, &item);
    }

    pHeaderCtrl->Invalidate();
    pHeaderCtrl->UpdateWindow();
}



